# Broken code on K&R?

Tags: c

At page29 of 'The C programming language' (Second edition) by K&R I've read a procedure I think is broken. Since I'm a beginner I would expect I'm wrong though I cannot explain why.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 // Maximum input line size

int get1line(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

// Print longest input line
int
main()
{
  int len;                // Current line lenght
  int max;                // Maximum lenght seen so far
  char line[MAXLINE];     // Current input line
  char longest[MAXLINE];  // Longest line saved here

  max = 0;
  while ((len = get1line(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    if (len > max) {
      max = len;
      copy(longest, line);
    }

  if (max > 0)            // There was a line to read
    printf("Longest string read is: %s", longest);

  return 0;
}

// `get1line()` : save a line from stdin into `s`, return `lenght`
int
get1line(char s[], int lim)
{
  int c, i;

  for (i = 0; i < lim -1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    s[i] = c;

  if (c == '\n') {
    s[i] = c;
    ++i;
  }

  s[i] = '\0';

  return i;
}


// `copy()` : copy `from` into `to`; assuming
// `to` is big enough.
void
copy(char to[], char from[])
{
  int i;

  i = 0;
  while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
    ++i;
}
```

My perplexity is: we're using the function `get1line` and suppose that at the end  of the `for`-loop `i` is set at `lim -1`. Then the following `if`-statement will update `i` at `lim`, causing the next instruction (the one which puts the `NULL` character at the end of the string) to corrupting the stack (since `s[lim]` is not allocated, in that case).

Is the code broken?

Comment: Questions on Code Review should contain your own code, and code that you would like to be critiqued. For questions about how someone else's code works, consult Stack Overflow.

Comment: A quibble: `NULL` is a null pointer constant. You mean "null character", not "NULL character".

Comment: K&R wrote some cryptic code... Don't learn this from them. But it does work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary: It's not possible to exit the loop with both `i == lim-1` and `c == '\n'`, so the case you are worried about never arises.

In detail: We can rewrite the for loop (while preserving its meaning) to make the order of events clear.

```
i = 0;
for (;;) {
    if (i >= lim-1) break;      /* (1) */
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF) break;        /* (2) */
    if (c == '\n') break;       /* (3) */
    s[i] = c;
    ++i;
}
```

At loop exit (1) it can't be the case that `c == '\n'` because if that were the case then the loop would have exited at (3) the previous time around.*

At loop exits (2) and (3) it can't be the case that `i == lim-1` because if that were the case then the loop would have exited at (1).

* This depends on `lim` being at least 2, so that there was in fact a previous time around the loop. The program only ever calls `get1line` with `lim` equal to `MAXLINE`, so this is always the case.**

** You could make make the function safe when `lim` is less than 2 by initializing `c` to a value other than `'\n'` before the loop begins. But if you are concerned about this possibility, then you might also want to be concerned about the possibility that `lim` is `INT_MIN`, so that `lim-1` results in undefined behaviour due to integer overflow.

Comment: About the last note. When you're talking about _safety_, ("initializing `c` at a value which is *not* `\n`"), you're referring to that _in principle_  `c` can have any value before being set --making the procedure undetermined? Moreover, since in my system `int`-type is implemented in terms of a *signed*-type and `lim` has _logical_ sense only when positive (it is a lenght), I can't cause an integer overflow. Am I wrong? :-)

Comment: (1) A variable like `c` with automatic storage duration is *indeterminate* until it is set: it could have any value, including `'\n'`. (2) You could cause integer overflow by calling `get1line(s, INT_MIN)`.

Answer (score 1):

The code is wrong if `lim == 0` because it uses `c` uninitialised and adds the \0. 
It is also wrong if `lim == 1` because it uses `c` uninitialised. Calling the function with `lim < 2` is not very useful, but it should not fail like this.

If `lim > 1` then the function is OK

```
for (i = 0; i < lim -1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
   s[i] = c;
```

The loop exits either if `i == lim-1` or if `c == EOF` or if `c == '\n'`.

- If the first condition is true (`i == lim-1`), then the last condition is definitely not true (unless `lim < 2`, as noted above).
- If the first condition is false (`i < lim-1`), then even if the loop exits with `c == \n`, we know that there is space in the buffer because we know that `i < lim-1`.